# Laravel 5 input old is empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My routes is here

```
Route::get('sign-up', ['as' => 'signUp', 'uses' => 'UserController@signUpGet']);
Route::post('sign-up', ['as' => 'signUpPost', 'uses' => 'UserController@signUpPost']);
```

Controller

```
return redirect('signUp')->withInput();
```

And View

```
    <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{route('signUpPost')}}"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
</form>
```

The {{old()}} function return empty value.

EDIT

I took

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:
```

Comment: Are your sessions working correctly?

Comment: Yes, my sessions working correctly

Comment: Are you sure the input is been sent? I dont see any submit button within the `<form>`?

Comment: I tested my form, it work. I have got submit button

Comment: Yes - but in your controller - BEFORE the redirect - if you do `dd(Input::all())` - is the username filled in there?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your problem looks like you are not actually submitting the username in the first place:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{route('signUpPost')}}"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
</form>
```

There is no 'submit' button inside the form. If you submit outside the form - then the `username` will not be included.

Add the submit button inside your form - then try again

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{route('signUpPost')}}"> 
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Edit - also your controller is wrong. It should be this:

```
 return redirect()->route('signUp')->withInput();
```

Comment: I should use  redirect() ?. redirect() return error (NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:). if i use view('sign_up') its not working :(. I added submit button

Comment: Post your full controllers

Comment: My Controller http://laravel.io/bin/9vR4R
My Routes http://laravel.io/bin/Delwy
My views http://laravel.io/bin/PXxl3

Answer (score 13):

All you are missing is to Flash the Input to the session. This is so it's available during the next request.

```
     $request->flash();
```

Do that just before calling to View your form.

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#old-input

Comment: ->withInput() adds the Request::flash() / $request->flash() automatically

Answer (score 0):

My problem here was caused by "data-prefill" in the input. Once I removed this, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div class="form-group @if($errors->first('username')) has-error @endif">
              <label for="username" class="rtl">Enter user name </label>
              <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control rtl basic-usage" id="username" placeholder="Enter user name" value="{!! old('username') !!}">
              <span class="help-block required">{{$errors->first('username')}}</span>
            </div>
```

---

above form  field will show old value entered. 
will show validation error (you have to specify error separately.)
have a place holder.
bootstrap to look better.(add bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Your name in the register view should correspond with keys in create() and validate() method inside your RegisterController file.

Comment: Adding a code snippet that explains the answer in details would be great

Answer (score -3):

You can try this: `{{ Input::old('username') }}`.

Comment: It should be use return redirect('signUp')->withInput(); ?. If i use return view('signUp') your code not working. if i use redirect function . i took route error.